# Is asp.net 5 different from asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, there are templates for asp.net 5 (start site) and asp.net 5 mvc.  What is the difference between these two?

Webforms is supposed to be gone so asp.net 5 isn't webforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ASP.NET 5](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview) is a new platform including the following features:

- New flexible and cross-platform runtime
- New modular HTTP request pipeline
- Cloud-ready environment configuration
- Unified programming model that combines MVC, Web API, and Web Pages
- Ability to see changes without re-building the project
- Side-by-side versioning of the .NET Framework
- Ability to self-host or host on IIS
- New tools in Visual Studio 2015
- Open source in GitHub

ASP.NET MVC 5 is just the current stable version of the MVC framework based on ASP.NET 4.

I guess you are confusing it with the new ASP.NET MVC 6 which is part of ASP.NET 5.

So basically the template for ASP.NET MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2015 is there for backwards compatibility allowing you to still be able to create MVC applications on the old platform.

Comment: No - I'm not confusing it.  Check the first screenshot here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/23/aspnet-5-updates-for-feb-2015.aspx.  From what you are saying, asp.net MVC is part of asp.net 5.  But I'm not sure what the asp.net 5 template is.

Comment: Yes, what about this screenshot? Can't see any `ASP.NET MVC 5` in it. I suppose that this template just creates some predefined web application using ASP.NET MVC 6, Web API, and other stuff in it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all its not a thing to compare.

ASP.NET 5 is the latest release of asp.net framework series with lot of new  features. And ASp.net MVC is one approach (service/ framework) to develop web application(there are other approaches like web form and website). You can integrate MVC as a service to empty asp.net application and use.

ASP.NET 5 is cross platform also.

It is all packed in Visual studio 2015 where MVC templates are available.

Comment: Did you perhaps miss the existing answer?